# What is best way for storing paid contents of android application?

Tags: android

I am working on one android application,in which paid videos are contain, user will able to download that videos. But I am not sure where I am going to save it after downloaded. Since these are paid videos, So user can not copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Being videos I guess they would be quite large so the only real alternative is to store them on SD\USB storage but this does mean that they are freely accessible to be moved and copied.

You could restrict them to internal storage but space would be an issue on some devices and you would lose the protection if the device was rooted.

Maybe disallowing rooted devices and streaming the videos is the only safe option.

Answer (score 0):

Let user save anywhere their prefer (SD/USB storage), for secure content we must protect from both side: server and client. For client we can archive secure content by:

Step1: Encrypt content before save (Key generate base one user or device specific, or get key from server... or what ever combination )

Step2: When play we will decrypt content to piece of content then play with buffer data

Another keyword you may be want to try is DRM (Digital rights management)
Hope it help.

Comment: thanks nguyendat, but now problem is that, encryption of whole video file is not good as for performance. We can encrypt some few initial bytes of video file, and decrypt that bytes while playing. But problem is that if we consider initial 100 bytes for encryption then encrypted bytes are more than 100 bytes, so when we write encrypted bytes to file some bytes of video gets lost. please can you help me.